# PDFKIT iOS 11 , Save Annotations Page in PDFDocument

Tags: swift, swift4, ios11, pdfkit

I  have one PDF page for example in PDF Page 0. I change and add something in the page. Now I want to save in PDFDocument.

Here is my code 
here is my pdf Document:

```
var pdfDocument: PDFDocument?
pdfView.annotationsChanged(on: (pdfView.currentPage)!)
```

After this work the pdf change In Load but after reload I have the pdf without editing.

I know I can save like `pdfDocument?.write(to:)` but I want replace one page not all pdfDoucment if it's possible. If not, I want to save all pages with new change like a new pdf.

maybe I will use this but how

```
pdfDocument?.write(toFile: String, withOptions: [PDFDocumentWriteOption : Any]?)
```

Comment: @AamirR you don't have other solution or you try the other solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this Piece of code to Save the pdf Content. I assume you have the PDFDocument loaded

```
NSString *path = @"Name.pdf";
NSString *docsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *newPath = [docsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];

NSData * content = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation;        
[content writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES];
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath];
pdfdocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:newURL];
```